# Count facebook page posts likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was reading the fb api doc but I couldn't find a lot about the different type of queries you can build.

Im trying to count all the likes in the posts from certain facebook page of the day.

Does the API supports params like the date or Will I have to take a whole response like the one I get with this request and somehow sum the counts of the likes?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?fields=comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true)&access_token=XXXXXXX
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most graph api queries support a since, until params

you can try this based on your example

`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?fields=comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true)&access_token=XXXXXXX&since=2015-08-25&until=2015-08-26`